# Android Application Library References

Tags: android

I've been given the task of working on an application a group of developers worked on outside of my company. I've some knowledge of Android but not a lot. Can someone please tell me what the image below essentially means? With regards to the red "x" beside each reference

I am assuming it is something to do with the libraries they used to develop the app, but if that is the case why weren't those libraries present when I opened the project? And how would I go about implementing the libraries so I can get the application to work locally.

I'd appreciate any help.

[image: Project properties panel]

Comment: this are probably the local path to those folders for library reference used by those "outside company" developers. You need to update the path of those dependency jars accordingly in your local system or add the libraries  to the project build path directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its telling you that the libraries can't be found, you'd be better just deleting everything, reimporting them to your eclipse's workspace and adding them one by one

Comment: OK I'll do that Thanks. I figured it was something like that but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

These are all android library dependencies.  You need to open them as separate projects in Eclipse, and then link them together.  It's a workaround by Google to the fact android projects need asset files (like images and xml layouts) and jars can't do that.  All of these are publicly available libraries.  ActionBarSherlock is a library to ssupport action bar like functionality on Android2.3.  SlidingMenu is just that.  Facebook is facebook's official sdk.  Google Play Services is a library written by Google for accessing their web based services.  All of these can be downloaded for free off the web.  Then just load into Eclipse and fix the locations it's looking for the dependencies on disk, and it should work (assuming there's no version differences).

Since your work is professional, please note:  I don't know what the licenses on any of these are.  You'll need to evaluate that to see if any of them are a problem.

Or yell at the outside devs and tell them to provide you with the versions they compiled and tested against.  They ought to have done so.